# IFTT to Discord webhook trying to tigger other bots

Tags: discord, ifttt

im using alexa to post in to a discord via ifttt and webhooks, is it possible to get the webhook to trigger a bot like atlast.

```
{"content":"Party time guys, @here join voice. a!play don't stop me now"}
```

That is the content of the body and `a!play` should trigger a bot called atlas , is it possible to trigger a bot via a webhook?

Answer (score 0):

Hi, 
in theory, yes, you can trigger a bot from webhook. Anyway... if I understand correctly, you use alexa for your webhooks. On iftttt, you have a simpler method. Here are some videos that might help you :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LxMjo0Ov90

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smfglJ8jMkw

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KIPX9XRfRLA

Good day

Comment: Thank you, I'll check these out.